# All the wires are hot in a 3-way switch

Tags: electrical

I was trying to replace the old 3way switch with the smart switch. So I removed the switches from both the boxes to see which wire is the line and which is the load? But box1 has all 3 wires as hot and box2 has 2 wires hot. Box 2 also has an unused neutral wire. Any idea how is this possible? Can someone please have a diagram of this setup and explain it? Is it possible to install the smart 3way switch here in box2 which has neutral wire? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Home Improvement DIY. Please take the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) and then upload picture of the inside of your boxes. Highlight which wires are hot.

Comment: I suspect you have a carter style 3 way switch. Google will have wiring diagrams of it. I don't know if you can install a smart switch, you'll have to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved please?

Comment: I believe I have the same issue as someone mentioned in this link:
https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/226638/all-wires-hot-in-3-wire-cable-to-3-way-switches
If someone can please point me to the circuit diagram of this setup will be of great help. Thanks for your attention on this topic.